# CNAME set, but ignored. How to purge wrong DNS A record?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, cloudflare, a-record

I have configured a subdomain `blog.example.net` with dreamhost like this

```
blog    CNAME   mygreatblog.ghost.io
```

meaning `blog.example.net` points to `mygreatblog.ghost.io` via a CNAME record.

I can confirm the properly set CNAME here:

https://www.whatsmydns.net/#CNAME/blog.example.net

However, when I actually visit `blog.example.net` I keep ending up on a different website - a gitlab instance that I also host under a different subdomain on `example.net`.

I can even confirm that there is a wrong A record stored that points to an IP that I don't recognize (it seems to be some cloudflare-network IP):

https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/blog.example.net

Now this is what I tried:

- Open blog.example.net in an incognito window
- Refresh DNS at dreamhost, where the domain is registered with the nameservers
- Wait 12 hours
- Flush DNS cache at Google and OpenDNS

What I would like to do: Purge the cache of cloudflare. However, I don't even have an account with cloudflare (at least none that I am aware of). My gitlab instance uses cloudflare somehow but I can't find any documentation on that.

**So my question:**

Is this a DNS caching issue?

If yes, why did the dns flushes have no effect?

If this is *not* a DNS caching issue, what else could it be?

Comment: I'm not seeing *any* record for `blog.maxmuster.net`, and the link you reference shows the same. Bunch of red Xs on both CNAME and A links.

Comment: yeah sorry, I decided not to put the actual domain name there. The links aren't actually working.

Comment: Please don't do that. Use `example.com/net/org` or something like `foo.invalid` if you're providing non-functional examples. DNS questions like this usually need the actual domain to be readily answerable by us.

Comment: Isn't it ironic that I posted the question, got my answer - everything's great, the system works ... but I get downvotes and now the question is closed - signalling that this is not how I am supposed to ask questions here. A difficult case to make, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even without knowing the actual domain names the root cause is clear. A `CNAME` record isn't an HTTP *redirection* nor HTTP *reverse proxy*. The server at `mygreatblog.example.com` is not aware of hostname `blog.example.net` (sent by the web browser in HTTP `Host:` header) and doesn't know which site it should display. Therefore, you get whatever is configured as the default virtual host.

Possible solutions:

- Contant the service provider and ask if it's possible to add an alias to the virtualhost.
- Use your own server to perform an HTTP *redirection* (URL changes).
- Use your own server as a HTTP *reverse proxy*.

Comment: You solved it. Thank you very much indeed! At Ghost.io you can simply tell them that you use a different domain for your blog and that was it.

Comment: Do I get it right: mygreatblog.ghost.io was misconfigured - OK. But apparently, as a consequence, blog.example.net defaults on DNS level to an A record of some subdomain of example.com.